# ssrs drilldown report hide parent

Tags: reporting-services, charts, report, drilldown, pie-chart

I am creating a drilldown report in SSRS using pie chart. I have done the drilldown to the next chart but I also need to hide the parent chart once the child is visible. How can I achieve this? Please suggest.

Thank you.

Comment: Do you show the child chart also the first time when you run the report? If not, what is the visibility condition for the child chart? When do you want to make the parent chart visible again once is hidden?

Comment: No, the child chart will remain hidden by default. Once I click on one portion of the pie chart, the drillthrough data shows up in the child and the parent gets hidden. The parent chart can get shown up again through some link...havn't decided about it yet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve this by having a parameter for the report and based on his value, one chart will be visible and the other one hidden and reverse.
Follow this steps:

1. Create a new report and name it f.e TestDrillDown and add the both charts and set the series and data fields
2. Add a new parameter to the report and set its value to -1 (For example if you want to pass the "year" parameter between the parent chart to the detail chart, then name the parameter "Year")
3. Set the value of "Year" parameter when clicking on the any year in the pie chart:
   2.1. Click on the pie and then click on the Series Properties.
   2.2. Go to Action tab and click on option Go to report.
   2.3. Choose the same report f.e. TestDrillDown 
   2.4. Click on Add button and add parameter Name: "Year" and for the Value select the "year"
4. Now we can set the visibility of both charts: 
   3.1. Click on the chart properties
   3.2. Go to the visibility tab
   3.3. On show and hide based expression place this:

   - for the first chart: =IIF(Parameters!year.Value<0,false,true)
   - for the second chart: =IIF(Parameters!year.Value>0,false,true)

Now you only need to set the year parameter back to -1 when you want that the parent chart to be visible again.
You can check this link that presents a similar solution for what you need, except hiding the parent, but for that you can use the visibility condition above:
http://bi-commonsolution.blogspot.ro/2012/05/drilldown-dashboard-in-ssrs.html